# Delete json block with jq command

Tags: json, jq

I have json file with multiple domains which is formated as is showed below. How can I delete whole blocks with domains? For example if I will want to delete whole block in json for domain `domain.tld`?

I tryed this, but output is error:

```
jq '."http-01"."domain"[]."main"="domain.tld"' acme.json
jq: error (at acme.json:11483): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

formating example file:

```
    {
  "http-01": {
    "Account": {
      "Email": "mail@placeholder.tld",
      "Registration": {
        "body": {
          "status": "valid",
          "contact": [
            "mailto:mail@placeholder.tld"
          ]
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/110801506"
      },
      "PrivateKey": "main_priv_key_string",
      "KeyType": "4096"
    },
    "Certificates": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "www.some_domain.tld"
        },
        "certificate": "cert_string",
        "key": "key_string",
        "Store": "default"
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "some_domain.tld"
        },
        "certificate": "cert_string",
        "key": "key_string",
        "Store": "default"
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "www.some_domain2.tld"
        },
        "certificate": "cert_string",
        "key": "key_string",
        "Store": "default"
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "some_domain2.tld"
        },
        "certificate": "cert_string",
        "key": "key_string",
        "Store": "default"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete domain block "www.some_domain.tld" :

```
jq '."http-01".Certificates |= map(select(.domain.main != "www.some_domain.tld"))' input.json
```

Comment: This one seems promising works in jqplay.org...but when I apply that on file, the domain remains there.

I am confused of the bipolarity now..

Comment: Double check the domain name.

Comment: I did, I assume thats some linux bash issue, I will properly test it tomorrow with python. I go to sleep now, it is night here :) Thanks for help for now!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad. What is a "block"?

Let's assume you want to delete from within the object under `http-01` each field that is of type array and has at index `0` an object satisfying `.domain.main == "domain.tld"`. Then first navigate to where you want to delete from, and update it (`|=`) using `del` and `select` which performs the filtered deletion.

```sh
jq '
  ."http-01" |= del(
    .[] | select(arrays[0] | objects.domain.main == "domain.tld")
  )
' acme.json
```

```json
{
  "http-01": {
    "Account": {
      "Email": "email@domain.tld",
      "Registration": {
        "body": {
          "status": "valid",
          "contact": [
            "mailto:email@domain.tld"
          ]
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/110801506"
      },
      "PrivateKey": "long_key_string",
      "KeyType": "4096"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SdmDUsXNfF)

If your "block" is deeper, go deeper before updating. If it is higher, the whole document for instance, there's no need to update, just start with `del`.

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for not providing proper info. Not sure how it is called in terminology of json.

But simply said, I want to delete some domains in my script usin "jq" command so block in this case is whole domain and informations about it in acme.json.. Hope I clarified this now?

Comment: @Delirium It may help if you provided a minimal but valid and usable example showing what it looks like before and what it looks like after applying jq on it. That also facilitates proving whether a solution really does what you want it to. (You could play around on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/), if that helps. Take my [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SdmDUsXNfF) from above for starters.)

Comment: well what I provided is quiet accurate to my prod. file I just inputed placeholders for certs, keys and domains.

Anyway, when I try your example the domain info is deleted (keytype, privatekey, cert)

But there will still remain part of domain

      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "domain.tld"
        }
      }

Comment: Your sample may be accurate for you wrt the original data, but accuracy is a relative concept and as such your sample is not (yet) accurate to us wrt thoroughly understand what you are trying to accomplish. Therefore, to have a common ground which we can work on while you can still extrapolate the solution from, two samples are needed, one before and one after applying the jq filter, which are small enough to be posted here yet *accurate to you* in your sense while also being valid (i.e. complete wrt application) to be *accurate for us*. Hope that made sense.

Comment: so I edited example of my json file and filled it with dummy data.

I made it way shorter I have over 1k domains in that file but this is how they are all formated.

Comment: @Delirium Very good! Now another one that shows how the output of a solution applied to that sample should look like.